# Alternate Windows Chkdsk GUI to prompt to see details

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk, splash

I have a problem with my HD. So I run chkdsk /r/f - But now the verification stoped in 38% for more than 2h.

The PC looks normal, responding to keyboard. So, there's a way to alternate this screen to prompt for read details of operation?

Ps: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing from chkdsk is fairly typical when doing a physical level scan. If chkdsk finds an issue and is attempting to repair it, it can be at the same percent complete for many hours, even more than a day.

I think what you are asking for is a way to run chkdsk that provides more feedback so that you can be sure that it is still running and isn't frozen.

If thats the case, your best option is to use the verbose flag, /v; so you would call it as `chkdsk /r/f/v`.

This will provide more information, but you will still have long periods of time when there is no information output.

In short, it sounds like you do have one or more errors on the drive that chkdsk is trying to fix which can take a very long time, and it is extremely common for people to think that chkdsk has frozen in these cases. Add the verbose flag for a little more status info, but you really just need to let it run as long as it needs to. If it runs for an incredibly long time (2+ days), then you can be sure that it is either frozen or otherwise not working properly. Otherwise, just let it run until completion.

As a rough approximation, if you ran chkdsk /r/f on a 1TB drive that had no issues at all, you can expect it to take somewhere in the range of 3 to 6 hours. There are far too many variables involved to give an exact answer, but if you search around you'll find numbers in this area. Once an issue is identified by chkdsk, the amount of time becomes basically impossible to estimate - the tool is designed to recover data on corrupt sectors and it will do everything it can to do so with no time limits.

This is a good [writeup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187941) on chkdsk from microsoft.

#### Update

You can find the log created during that chkdsk run following these [directions](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-find-chkdsk-results-in-windows-10/)

There should be details in it regarding the issues found and whether unrepairable issues were found. Post the log if you'd like help interpreting it.

In any case:

#### You should back up everything that you can't replace on that drive asap.

Then either download the hard drive support / test utitlity from your hard drive manufacturer (preferred method) or a free utility such as passmark [disckcheck](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm). Either of these options will evaluate the health status of the hard drive (SMART status)

The question to be answered is if you have a hardware issue (failing drive) or a just a file system corruption. The former can easily cause the latter, which creates some confusion. The utilities I mentioned above evaluate the hardware state, and not the file system directly. chkdsk looks at the file system primarily.

If you can find the hdd manufacturers utility they will usually include full tests you can run on the drive, and typically will assist with warranty issues in the event of an identified hw issue, which is why that path is preferred.

Post your results - chkdsk log, hdd health check, hard drive make model, etc - for additional assistance.

Comment: It is possible to ascertain the operation of CHKDSK using Task Manager (Windows 8 and later) or Resource Monitor (Windows 7). Also Process Explorer and Process Hacker can show disk activity for each process, including CHKDSK.

Comment: If you are running a repair scan using chkdsk on your system drive it will not run in windows as the drive has to be unmounted. Normally it will run on the next restart. None of the things you mentioned will be available in this early stage of boot that chkdsk will run in. If its a non system drive; sure. But I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: Thanks. I let the process continue. After more 7 hours I out from home and let PC running chkdsk, still in 38%. When I back Windows have started. I don't know what happens. Windows still freezing when write. I concluded than my HD has phisical problems, I run chkdsk in windows prompt and chkdsk show HD block errors. There's a chance the problem is HD controller from motherboard or no?

Comment: Very unlikely to be controller but not impossible. I updated the answer with suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: It was HD. I replace it and PC works very well. Thanks!